# Arredondar valores para cima jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
$(".quantidade_lotes").change(function() {
    var quantidade_linhas = $("#quantidade_linhas").val();
    var quantidade_lotes = $(".quantidade_lotes").val();
    var quantidade_dividida = (quantidade_linhas/quantidade_lotes);
});
```

Nisto, quantidade_linhas é = 17, quantidade_lotes = 5, e quantidade_dividida = 3.4. Preciso que o resultado seja 4, arrendando sempre pra cima. Como eu posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode usar a função ceil();

```
Math.ceil(1.4)
```

Retorna 2;

[Fonte](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_ceil.asp)

Comment: Na verdade, o certo seria: Arrendar pra baixo e o que sobrar, eu jogo no último lote... Consegui entender @dsantoro?